# Colorbox not loading ajax URL in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, colorbox

I'm using a jQuery plugin called Colorbox (http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) and loading content via Ajax.  This works as expected in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE it loads the overlay, but doesn't load the ajax content.

Any ideas what could be causing this and possible solutions?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure it's not a CSS issue that's preventing you from seeing the content in IE?

Comment: Your right! Want to answer and I'll select you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it's not a CSS issue that's preventing you from seeing the content in IE?

(IE is a nightmare). $5 says the guys that developed IE never built a web site in their life.